# Nginx reverse proxy with client verification to NodeJs app

Tags: node.js, nginx, ssl, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup a reverse proxy with client certificate verification to a NodeJs app.

I'm getting `502 Bad Gateway`.

After reading Nginx docs and many questions still can't get it to work. My last try is this config:

```
events {
}

http {
    upstream app {
        server 127.0.0.1:8443;
        keepalive 64;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;

        ssl_certificate /home/marcos/certs/server.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/marcos/certs/server.key;
        
        ssl_client_certificate /home/marcos/certs/ca.crt;
        ssl_verify_client on;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            
                proxy_pass https://app/;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_read_timeout 300s;
                proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
        }   

    }
}
```

The error on `/var/log/nginx/error.log` is:

```
2021/03/09 22:21:44 [crit] 6083#6083: *107 SSL_read() failed (SSL: error:1409445C:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv13 alert certificate required:SSL alert number 116) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:8443/", host: "localhost"
```

Using `nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)` and selfsigned certificates.

When the client certificate verification is disabled on my App and Nginx, it works.

Comment: From `https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446#section-4.4.2.4`:
"If the client does not send any certificates (i.e., it sends an empty Certificate message), the server MAY at its discretion either continue the handshake without client authentication or abort the handshake with a "certificate_required" alert.  Also, if some aspect of the certificate chain was unacceptable (e.g., it was not signed by a known, trusted CA), the server MAY at its discretion either continue the handshake (considering the client unauthenticated) or abort the handshake."

Comment: @AndrWeisR The client certificate is installed at the browser, when i go directly to the app server, it send the certificate and it works. Also the certificate at `ssl_client_certificate` signed the client certificate. Have any idea how can I fix the nginx config to make it work?